# How deep variant and others preprocessed insertion and deletion for extracting candidate variant?

Tags: variant-calling

I am trying to build a model for variant calling,but I am a bit confused how to pre-process the reads that has insertion and deletion and align them with reference?

Should I add something to the location of insertion or deletion to reference or should I just delete from read?

Comment: Can you provide some reference for why you think preprocessing is necessary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you building a model specifically for deep variant, or trying to create your own model via a different algorithm?